# Spring MVC RestController Ambiguous PathVariable mapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have 2 **GET** handler methods

```
 @RestController
 public class TestController {

    ...

    @GetMapping(name = "/test")
    public Test testMethod() {
        return testService.getTest();
    }

    @GetMapping(name = "/test/{count}")
    public List<Test> getTestList2(@PathVariable(name = "count") Integer count) {

        return testService.getTestList(count);
    }
 }
```

And I get error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'testController' method 
public java.util.List<models.Test> TestController.getTestList2(java.lang.Integer)
to {[],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'testController' bean method
```

If I comment one method all work fine

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing mistake is you are telling `@GetMapping` name rather that its value, It might feel both of them works the same way but it has tiny differences.

> **RequestMapping.name**: Assign a name to this mapping.

and

> **RequestMapping.value**: The primary mapping expressed by this annotation. Supported at the type level as well as at the method level! When used at the type level, all method-level mappings inherit this primary mapping, *narrowing it for a specific handler method*.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

     @GetMapping(value = "/test")
     public String testMethod() {
        return "Hello from test";
     }

     @GetMapping(value = "/test/{count}")
     public String testMethod(@PathVariable(value = "count") Integer count) {
        return "Hello from Parameterized Test. Count: " + count;
     }
}
```

Hence you are specifying the path or route of your Controller it all always preferable to specify the `value`

Comment: @ip696 you are not hitting the correct url. It should be  
**localhost:8080/test/3** . Any way I rewrote the answer and tested myself. Read it again and try. It should fix your problem.